# InvalidSelectorException thrown despite the Xpath being syntactically correct

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

In my webdriver script, I'm trying to get a webElement[which happens to be a page heading] & fetching the locators & locations through the **.properties** file.

First & foremost query is that if your xpath is syntactically correct, do you get such an exception[Exception given below]?. I'm confused at this point because of the message appended along with the exception which is **cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement**

Setup Details,

OS                  => Windows 7

Browser             => IE 9

Webdriver version   => 2.44.0.0

IE driver server    => 32 bit

Following is the xpath[copied from the properties file],

```
.//*[@id='frmPDAuditReports']//table[@class='PageHeading']/tbody/tr/td
```

Code for getting the webElement is,

```
public WebElement pageHeading() throws Exception
{
        boolean elementFoundMessage = CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageObjectRetriever.customElementWaitWithTimeoutWithProperties(driver,CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageObjectRetriever.getLocator("pageHeading", "Page Heading"),elementTimeout);
        if(elementFoundMessage)
        {
             element = CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageObjectRetriever.returnWebElement(driver, CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageObjectRetriever.getLocator("pageHeading", "Page Heading"));
        }
        else
        {
            log.error("PageHeading():Element not found: Null Returned");
        }


        return element;
}
```

Concerned part of the properties file looks like,

```
pageHeading  = xpath : .//*[@id='frmPDAuditReports']//table[@class='PageHeading']/tbody/tr/td
```

Now, the xpath is syntactically correct & i have verified it through the firepath.For that fact the xpath actually worked fine during most of my executions.Just once the exception was thrown, which is given below,

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The xpath expression './/*[@id='frmPDAuditReports']//table[@class='PageHeading']/tbody/tr/td' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 47 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'OTINWISRCDT050', ip: '172.24.185.103', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_71'
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=.//*[@id='frmPDAuditReports']//table[@class='PageHeading']/tbody/tr/td}
Session ID: c613b73a-e941-4847-ae49-06bcae108cdd
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=1, ignoreZoomSetting=true, enablePersistentHover=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=9, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, requireWindowFocus=true, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:47437/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]
ERROR[CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageObjects]: PageHeading():Element not found: Null Returned
ERROR[CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageServices]: PageHeading(): Page Heading element not found !!
ERROR[CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageServices]: PageHeading(): Failed
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:383)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementsByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:459)
at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElements(By.java:353)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElements(RemoteWebDriver.java:346)
at Utilities.ObjectRetriever.customElementWaitWithTimeoutWithProperties(ObjectRetriever.java:172)
at PageObjects.CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageObjects.pageHeading(CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageObjects.java:34)
at ServicesOfPage.CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageServices.getPageHeading(CreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPageServices.java:58)
at Tests.isNavigatedToCreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPage.compareHomePageHeading(isNavigatedToCreatePolicyApprovalDeviationRequestPage.java:32)
at Execution.TestExecution.TC(TestExecution.java:254)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
```

I'm finding it extremely difficult to figure out what is/are the possible things that went wrong for this particular execution,Help me!

Any help will be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

I can see three reasons why it doesn't work.

---

1) *Wrong XPath*:
I recommend installing Google Chrome. In Chrome when you Inspect Element, you can right click on an element, and directly copy XPath.

2) *Page heading gets loaded asynchronously*:
Are you sure the website doesn't load your element asynchronously? Try disabling JavaScript and load the website to see if the element is there.

3) *Browser error*?:
This can sometimes happen, and IE is not a very good browser for Selenium. You could try Firefox or headless browser like PhantomJS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! but find my comments for your points,    1. The xpath is not wrong, i can say this because i successfully located the element using the same Xpath in firepath. Also it failed only once in simultaneous 20 executions.    2. I've used webdriver wait for the element so there should be no problem with synchronization. Even if it is what you said, i'm not sure that it should throw **InvalidSelectorException** for that !!!    3. Its business requirment, can't change the browser . .!! but it would serve me better if you can pin point possible problems with IE in this regard.

Comment: If it only rarely happens, you could use something like this:

`try { /*insert your code here*/ } catch { /*if something fails try reloading the page and try again*/ }`

I'm not exactly sure if `try` and `catch` are in Java, but there should be